# Woocommerce add_to_cart() for product with variation doesn't work after update to v4.6

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

After update to Woocommerce v4.6 my function in custom made ajax cart doesn't work

`WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation_attributes);`

This function from above returns 'false'.

When I remove $variation_id and $variation_attributes it returns success. So I have no idea what is the problem with variations it used to work perfectly fine on the older version.

Even if I try with hardcoded values that function returns false.

[image]

So even if I try:

`WC()->cart->add_to_cart(29367, 1, 29368)` function returns 'false'

[image]

**UPDATE --- SOLUTION**

After few hours of thinkering I've found that validation for the forth parameter of add_to_cart() function has changed and it's more strict now.

So if I want to add variation I have to have right parameter keys. Previously it was working fine but now I need to be more specific.

In the previous version I had for example:

`$variation_attributes = ["pa_color"=>"purple", "pa_size"=>"s"];`

now I need to change keys to for example:

`$variation_attributes = ["attribute_pa_color"=>"purple", "attribute_pa_size"=>"s"]`

Comment: @LoicTheAztec sorry but you are wrong after few hours I've found what was the problem. It's not a software bug. The fourth parameter in that function should be an array with attributes earlier I was accepting two attributes for example: ["pa_color"=>"purple","pa_size"=>"s"] and now after update because the validation is better that was causing the error I have to provide ["attribute_pa_color"=>"purple","attribute_pa_size"=>"s"] so the problem is that in front of the attributes after the update I have to have "attribute_" part...

Comment: Your initial question wasn't showing anything related to attribute array formatted imput, **so nobody was able to guess what was the problem**. Anyways you should always wait some time before updating to a major version… Now you should answer your own question and then in few days accepting it as the good answer, to help people that have similar problem.